# Conditionally process (bgzip, tabix) files using loop and if else statement

Tags: r, if-statement, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have some `.vcf` files. I have selected those files from my directory and want to convert them to two other formats.

I am a bit confused using `if` and `else if` here. I want to do it like this: if there isn't `.bgz` file for `[i]`th `.vcf` file, I want to convert it to `.bgz` file keeping the original file.

If there is already `.bgz` file, but not `.bgz.tbi` file for `[i]` th `.bgz` file, then I want to convert  `.bgz` file to `.bgz.tbi` file keeping the original `.bgz` that I get from `.vcf` file.

Can someone please help me finish this loop? It works for if condition, but don't know how to proceed from there.

```
  path.file<-"/mypath/for/files/" 
  all.files <- list.files("/mypath/for/files")
  all.files <- all.files[grepl(".vcf$",all.files)]

for (i in 1:length(all.files)){
 if(!exists(paste0(all.files[i],".bgz"))){
  bgzip(paste0(path.file,all.files[i]), overwrite=FALSE)
  }else{(!exists(paste0(all.files[i],".bgz",".tbi"))){
  #if(!exists(paste0(all.files[i],".bgz",".tbi"))){
  indexTabix(paste0(paste0(path.file,all.files[i]),".bgz"), format="vcf")
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please NOTE: everything `.bgz` should be `.gz` here in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
#get VCF files with path
all.files <- list.files("/mypath/for/files", pattern = "*.vcf$",
                        full.names = TRUE)

for (i in all.files) {
  #make output names, so we don't mess about with paste
  file_bgz <- paste0(i, ".bgz")
  file_bgz_tbi <- paste0(i, ".bgz.tbi")

  #if bgz exists don't zip else zip
  if(!exists(file_bgz))
    bgzip(i, paste0(i, ".bgz"))

  #if tbi exists don't index else tabix
  if(!exists(file_bgz_tbi))
    indexTabix(file_bgz, format = "vcf")
  }
```